# How to save Gift Message to quote item

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to save my custom message to the quote items. How do I do that? What file should I modify and the best approach for this? Been looking for tutorial but I got no answer

Comment: Do you want  to use default Magento Gift Message?

Comment: @AmitBera actually if I can use the scripts/code for the existing I'm good with that. The problem is I removed the default Gift Message option and added a new field without using the default view for the gift message

Comment: So, now ,` gift message ` field is a custom field at your system?

Comment: @AmitBera not really it's still the same field I just used different html element to handle the value of the message